# Organize tidal-locking Qs with a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems to me that there are a number of questions dealing with tidally locked planets or moons, and as the fresh dup question suggests, these are not easily discoverable.

But I like to point out that **locking** might not be the common case. So how about a new tag for [spin-orbit-resonance](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spin-orbit-resonance) with [tidal-locking](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-locking) as a synonym?

What names would be better?

How many questions do we have that ought to be so tagged?

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer [tidally-locked](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidally-locked). It's the term most commonly used to describe the planets and moons, and people usually are asking about worlds that are already locked, not the process by which locking happens, although I would put that within the scope of the tag.

Answer (score 3):

[tidal-locking](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-locking) seems good to me. Easy to recognize.

[spin-orbit-resonance](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spin-orbit-resonance) might be more technically correct, but I doubt people will recognize it easily enough for the tag to be useful. Also, for most questions that really needs one side to the sun, resonance tag is a bad choice. Other resonances (if exists) can't give results people expect from locked planet. So if other resonances exists, it is not a synonym, but rather a broader tag. I don't recall any single question that would need this broader definition, and all existing ones call for tidally locked and nothing else - anything else would be unsuitable for OPs' purpose.

Note that **challenging question's premise is already considered acceptable**, so this in no way prevents anyone from answering like *“you’ll really get 3:2 in that case”*.

Comment: But as synonyms people will find the easy one, and then when the Answe says “you’ll really get 3:2 in that case” it still fits.

Comment: @JDługosz I came from Drupal, where rule was don't create synonyms, unless already in use. And if I want tidally locked planet, I don't want another resonances - it would make me avoid the tag at all.

Comment: Because the Answers explore the more general case (lots of people just *assume* tidal locking is the norm), I think the organising tag should be more general.  The wiki and summary can explain this.

Comment: Answers are not limited by tags. And if all questions are about tidal locks, why to force broader tag? Maybe put a sample, 10 newest questions about tidal locking and 10 newest questions about other kinds? This way, we could see if these has anything in common. And if there is no 10 questions about other kinds, then tag is not needed. At least, not yet.

Comment: I tend to prefer the less-granular, perhaps a simple "orbital mechanics" tag ?       (- non-stellar bodies, low or no handwavium, bring your best Newtonian physics along)

Comment: @Joe http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbital-mechanics it does exist. It's just too broad tag for this specific set of questions. Tidally locked worlds are a class on their own

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going with a more general tag, perhaps [orbits](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbits), [orbital-dynamics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbital-dynamics), or (my preference) [orbital-properties](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbital-properties).  So the tag would include (and somewhat organize) related questions re eccentricity or inclination of orbits -- and how such properties can influence worlds.

Comment: We already have [tag:orbital-mechanics], which is much broader (and has [tag:orbits] as a synonym).